# Finding Anagrams with vowels always at the end

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I was trying out this question :

Write a function using Recursion to display all anagrams of a string entered by the user, in such a way that all its vowels are located at the end of every anagram. (E.g.: Recursion => Rcrsneuio, cRsnroieu, etc.) Optimize it.

From this site :
http://erwnerve.tripod.com/prog/recursion/magic.htm

This is what i have done :

```
public static void permute(char[] pre,char[] suff) {
    if (isEmpty(suff)) {
        //result is a set of string. toString() method will return String representation of the array.
        result.add(toString(moveVowelstoEnd(pre)));
        return;
    }
    int sufflen = getLength(suff); //gets the length of the array
    for(int i =0;i<sufflen;i++) {
        char[] tempPre = pre.clone();
        char[] tempSuf = suff.clone();
        int nextindex = getNextIndex(pre); //find the next empty spot in the prefix array
        tempPre[nextindex] = tempSuf[i];
        tempSuf = removeElement(i,tempSuf); //removes the element at i and shifts array to the left
        permute(tempPre,tempSuf);
    }

}

public static char[] moveVowelstoEnd(char[] input) {
    int c = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<input.length;i++) {
        if(c>=input.length)
            break;
        char ch = input[i];
        if (vowels.contains(ch+"")) {
            c++;            
            int j = i;
            for(;j<input.length-1;j++)
                input[j] = input[j+1];
            input[j]=ch;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Last part of the question is 'Optimize it'. I am not sure how to optimize this. can any one help?

Comment: permute consonants, permute vowels, append the resultant vowel set to consonant set. that would be the optimization I suppose. It looks like you may be doing that here?

Comment: I am permuting everything and moving the vowels to the end. Then adding to the set. So here what i can see is that, many of the permutations are redundant since once the vowels are moved to the end, they might be same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group all the vowels into v

Group all consonants into w

For every pair of anagrams, concat the results

Comment: a way that `all` its vowels are located at the end of every anagram

Comment: This is undoubtedly the best "top level" strategy. The real fun will come when the OP tries to sort groups of vowels or consonants which contain duplicates, like abracadabra. If he just uses brute force and collapses the options, for abracadabra alone he will be generating 5!2!2! or 480 times as many permutations as he should. A fully optimized algorithm would generate each possible permutation exactly once; googling "algorithm to generate combinations with duplicates" provides some algorithms.